# how to integrate google docs with php?

Tags: php, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

pls help me for integrating google docs for php . I want to use google docs as a database for my application in php . I want to upload and download files to google docs irrespective of using php ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the newer Google Drive API, which allows you to perform the same tasks as the Documents List API and has completely new PHP client library and samples:

https://developers.google.com/drive/

Answer (score 2):

The [Zend Framework gdata API](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.docs.html) is probably where you want to get started.  Once you have some code that needs help, we'll be happy to help.

If you provide more details about your requirements by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11483464/edit) (there's an edit link under your question), we may be able to provide more detailed answers.